# Company uses Microsoft exchange for their mails . We have PHP web application. When user clicks Submit button the mail have to send

Tags: php, gmail, exchange-server, phpmailer

company uses Microsoft Exchange for their mail, They have PHP web application. during user submitting there should be sent mail. Give me ideas what to do. I saw PHPMAILER and i think it can only send by gmail. Did you have experience like this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHPMailer has no such limitation. You can send via several different mechanisms, including SMTP that will work just fine for sending through Exchange.

Comment: I have not have address like smtp.gmail.com . i have shockwave.lomisi.ge

Comment: It makes no difference. You can use any host name.